# Why is double.NaN not equal to itself?

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone explain this to me? In C# double.NaN is not equal to double.NaN

```
bool huh = double.NaN == double.NaN; // huh = false
bool huh2 = double.NaN >= 0; // huh2 = false
bool huh3 = double.NaN <= 0; // huh3 = false
```

What constant can I compare to a double.NaN and get true?

Comment: Just to explain your huhs : NaN is equal to nothing, not even itself. This is by definition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: What I think is unfortunate is that the context is lost. If we had two doubles, and both were assigned a value of NaN in order to represent the actual value 1/0. They should be equal, but since the context is lost, they're treated as not equal

Comment: You are right, an extra line of code should have to be implemented for that particular case.

Comment: mathematically correct. Why would one think one nan would be equal to another? sqrt( -1 ) != 1/0

Comment: It is just like **`NULL`** in SQL

Comment: @MichaelMeadows 1/0 is Inf, not NaN.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

If you are curious, this is what `Double.IsNaN` looks like:

```
public static bool IsNaN(double d)
{
    return (d != d);
}
```

Funky, huh?

Comment: That is weird allright. But then again, so is the declaration of NaN: `public const double NaN = (double) 1.0 / (double) 0.0;`

Comment: @Fedrik: as funky as this looks, you really should play with imitating that definition. You will get different results if you use double.NaN and double myNaN = (double)1.0 / (double)0.0; as the test (especifically, the former will test as false for IsInfinity and the latter as true!)

Comment: @Fredik, @Erich: Division by Zero will give inf (or, +inf, -inf based on the operands), 0 / 0 (among others) results in a NaN. There's a nice table with special operations/results at http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

Comment: @Erick Mirabal: BTW, where did you find out what IsNaN looks like? There's some times I need to see the implementation of certain .net methods.

Comment: @Carlo You can use .NET Reflector or use the Microsoft source server when debugging.

Comment: @Torsten: yes, I know division by zero gives you Infinity. But what I find funky is that double.NaN is defined as a number divided by zero, yet it fails the IsInfinity test!  @Carlo, as Adrian notes, .NET Reflector is what I used. I use it *all* the time to check implementation ideas and details.

Comment: To add to the confusion, object.Equals(double.NaN, double.NaN) returns true

Comment: @FredrikMörk "so is the declaration of NaN:" -- why lie? This answer gave the actual definition of IsNaN, whereas you just made something up.

Comment: "double.NaN is defined as a number divided by zero" -- no it isn't. 0/0 has no mathematical meaning and is thus "not a number"; there are many other ways to get "non a number".

Comment: @JimBalter You are correct that my comment was wrong: the reference source is actually saying `public const double NaN = (double)0.0 / (double)0.0;` [link to the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs#dcd7a869fad1e6bb). Thanks for pointing that out. On another note: being wrong and lying are two completely different things

Comment: @FredrikMörk As I said, you just made it up; you never saw any such declaration. Therefore it was a lie, not merely wrong.

Comment: Not sure if this was correct when you posted it, but IsNaN is [defined differently](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ef1e2ab328087c61a6878c1e84f4fc5d710aebce/src/mscorlib/src/System/Double.cs#L92) today.

Answer (score 47):

Use [Double.IsNaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan.aspx).

Answer (score 17):

```
bool isNaN = Double.IsNaN(yourNumber)
```

Answer (score 13):

The behavior is on purpose. The reason being NaN represents something that *is not a number* and so that is sort of a catch-all for many things.

The proper way to compare something to being NaN is to use the [IsNaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan.aspx) function.

Answer (score 8):

Use [Double.IsNan()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan(VS.71).aspx) to test for equality here. The reason is that NaN is not a number.

Answer (score 7):

There's a specialized function for this:

```
double.IsNan(huh);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the method "Double.IsNaN( value )" to check for this condition.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you already found the way to check if a IEEE-754 floating point number is [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN): it is the only floating point value (or range of values, because there are several NaNs) that evaluates to `False` if compared to itself, i.e. :

```
bool isNaN(double v) {
    return v != v;
}
```

Under the hood, the Double.IsNaN method might actually do the same thing. You should still use it, because the behavior is quite surprising to anybody who does not know about the FP standard.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that we know about NaN is that it's "Not a Number."  That doesn't mean that it has a value that is associable with its state.  For example:

∞ + (-∞) = NaN

0/0 = NaN

(∞ + (-∞)) <> (0/0)

Here's some C# to demonstrate

```
var infinity = 100d / 0;
var negInfinity = -100d / 0;

var notANumber = infinity + negInfinity;
Console.WriteLine("Negative Infinity plus Infinity is NaN: {0}", double.IsNaN(notANumber));

var notANumber2 = 0d / 0d;
Console.WriteLine("Zero divided by Zero is NaN: {0}", double.IsNaN(notANumber2));

Console.WriteLine("These two are not equal: {0}", notANumber == notANumber2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason of `Double.NaN != Double.NaN` is simple:

Do you expect `0/0` to be the same as `Math.Sqrt(-3)`? And same as `Math.Sqrt(-7)`?

There is a bug in C# in my opinion where `Equals()` is not overridden for NaN.

```
Assert.IsTrue(Double.NaN != Double.NaN);
Assert.IsTrue(Double.NaN.Equals(Double.NaN));
```

At the same time

```
Assert.IsTrue(Double.PositiveInfinity == Double.NegativeInfinity);
Assert.IsTrue(Double.PositiveInfinity.Equals(Double.PositiveInfinity));
// same for Double.NegativeInfinity and Single
```

Use static functions for `Double` and `Single`, e.g.

```
Double.IsNaN(value) && Double.IsInfinity(value);
```

Or more specific:

```
Double.IsPositiveInfinity(value);
Double.IsNegativeInfinity(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

> > The Equality operator considers two NaN values to be unequal to one another. In general, Double operators cannot be used to compare Double.NaN with other Double values, although comparison methods (such as **Equals** and **CompareTo**) can. see below examples

Referenced from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Double i = Double.NaN;
        while (!i.Equals(i)) //this would be result in false
        //while(i != i) // this would result in true.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

[here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/puoyr8) is .net fiddle for the same.