# double.NaN - how does this counterintuitive feature work?

Tags: double, nan

I stumbled upon .NET's definition of [`double.NaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx) in code:

```
public const double NaN = (double)0.0 / (double)0.0;
```

This is done similarly in `PositiveInfinity` and `NegativeInfinity`.

[`double.IsNaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan.aspx) (with removing a few #pragmas and comments) is defined as:

```
[Pure] 
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
public static bool IsNaN(double d) 
{
    if (d != d)
    { 
        return true; 
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is very counter-intuitive to me.

Why is NaN defined as division by zero? How is `0.0 / 0.0` represented "behind the scenes"? How can division by 0 be possible in `double`, and why does `NaN != NaN`?

Comment: This is more about NaN than .NET's specifics... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: possible duplicate of [double.NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145443/double-nan)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I agree, thanks for pointing that out and for the link! Changed the question a bit, to be less .NET specific.

Comment: its compatibile with database-null. There is also a rule that says that null != null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fairly simple answer here.  .Net framework has implemented the floating point standard specified by the IEEE [(`System.Double` complies with the IEC 60559:1989 (IEEE 754) standard for binary floating-point arithmetic.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).  This is because floating point arithmetic actually has to work across many systems, not just x86/64 architectures, so by following the conventions this ensures that there will be less compatibility issues (for instance porting code from a DSP into an x86 processor).

As for the d != d, this is a performance optimisation.  Basically this instruction relies on a hardware instruction which can very quickly determine if two double floating point numbers are equal.  Under the standard, NAN != NAN and therefore is the fastest way to test.  Trying to find a reference for you.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a performance optimization. Rather, this is the standard (and probably the only portable) way of testing for NaN which works by definition.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is NaN defined as division by
>   zero? How can division by 0 be
>   possible in double, and why does NaN
>   != NaN?

All of these are mandated by the [IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), which pretty much all modern CPUs implement.

> How is 0.0 / 0.0 represented "behind the scenes"?

By having an exponent with all bits set to 1 and a mantissa with at least one bit set to 1. Note that this means that there are a large number of different bit patterns that all represent NaN - but, as mentioned above, even if the bit patterns are identical, they must be considered not equal (i.e. == must return false).

Answer (score 0):

From the C# Spec:

> 14.9.2 Floating-point comparison operators
>   The predefined floating-point comparison operators are:
>
> > bool operator ==(float x, float y); bool operator ==(double x, double y);
> >     bool operator !=(float x, float y); bool operator !=(double x, double y);
> >     bool operator <(float x, float y); bool operator <(double x, double y);
> >     bool operator >(float x, float y); bool operator >(double x, double y);
> >     bool operator <=(float x, float y); bool operator <=(double x, double y);
> >     bool operator >=(float x, float y); bool operator >=(double x, double y);
>
> The operators compare the operands according to the rules of the IEC 60559 standard:
>   **If either operand is NaN, the result is false for all operators except !=, for which the result is true.** For any two operands, x != y always produces the same result as !(x == y). However, when one or both operands are NaN, the <, >, <=, and >= operators do not produce the same results as the logical negation of the opposite operator. [Example: If either of x and y is NaN, then x < y is false, but !(x >= y) is true. end example]

As to how NaN is represented behind the scenes, the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) on the IEEE spec has some examples.