# Why float.NaN != double.NaN in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, nan

Why `float.NaN != double.NaN` ?

while `float.PositiveInfinity == double.PositiveInfinity` and `float.NegativeInfinity == double.NegativeInfinity` are **equal**.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
bool PosInfinity = (float.PositiveInfinity == double.PositiveInfinity); //true
bool NegInfinity = (float.NegativeInfinity == double.NegativeInfinity); //true

bool isNanEqual = (float.NaN == double.NaN);  //false, WHY?
```

Comment: Please, anyone give some examples when a number becomes NaN.

Comment: Have you noticed that `double.NaN != double.NaN` too?

Comment: See also "Why is double.nan not equal to itself" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145443/why-is-double-nan-not-equal-to-itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is double.NaN not equal to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145443/why-is-double-nan-not-equal-to-itself)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`NaN` is never equal to `NaN` (even within the same type). Hence why the [IsNaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan.aspx) function exists:

```
Double zero = 0;
// This will return true.
if (Double.IsNaN(0 / zero)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Double.IsNan() can determine whether a value is not-a-number.");
}
```

---

You should also be aware that none of the comparisons you've shown are actually occurring "as is". When you write `floatValue == doubleValue`, the floats will actually be implicitly converted to doubles before the comparison occurs.

Answer (score 29):

Probably because [`NaN != NaN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Floating_point)

Answer (score 10):

To quote [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN):

> A comparison with a NaN always returns an unordered result even when comparing with itself.

Comment: just like transact sql, NULL is allways different from NULL :P