# how can i filter out NaN values and replace it with another value

Tags: c#, listview, nan

iv'e tried using a for loop to filter out the null and nan values but still the nan value is added to the listview. this is just a part where the calculation is done.

```
double rs1 = (qz1 * c11) + (asg1 * c22) + (sw1 * c33) + (prj1 * c44) + (pxm1 * c55) + (atti1 * c66);
if(rs1 != double.NaN || rs1 != null)
{
lst.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(rs1, 2).ToString());
}
else
{
lst.SubItems.Add("0");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is double.NaN not equal to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145443/why-is-double-nan-not-equal-to-itself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `IsNan` static function , read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Your code should look like this

```
if(!Double.IsNaN(rs1)  || rs1 != null)
```

NaN with NaN will always return false, [this is MSDN about NaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Two NaN values are considered unequal to one another. Therefore, it is not possible to determine whether a value is not a number by using the equality operator to compare it to another value that is equal to NaN

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when you test for inequality with double.NaN, it always returns true (the value itself is undefined). It's better to use `double.IsNaN(rs1)`.

Answer (score 1):

First, it can't be null because double is value type not reference type.So `rs1 != null` is redundant.Second you should use [`IsNaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method instead of check equality with `==`

```
if(!double.IsNaN(rs1))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(!Double.IsNaN(rs1)(float x = 0; x = (float)rs1;}`