# C# Remove NaN from List<object>

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of type StackBuilder:

```
public class StackBuilder
{
    private int quoteID = 0;
    private double price = 0;
    private double size = 0;

    public int QuoteID
    {
        get { return quoteID; }
    }

    public double Price
    {
        get { return price; }
    }

    public double Size
    {
        get { return size; }
    }

    public StackBuilder(int quoteID, double price, double size)
    {
        this.quoteID = quoteID;
        this.price = price;
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to remove all the elements that have price equal to NaN. This is what I have but for some reason it won't work.

```
BidStack.RemoveAll(item => item.Price == Double.NaN);
AskStack.RemoveAll(item => item.Price == Double.NaN);
```

Any suggestions?

SOLVED:

```
BidStack.RemoveAll(item => Double.IsNaN(item.Price));
AskStack.RemoveAll(item => Double.IsNaN(item.Price));
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145443/why-is-double-nan-not-equal-to-itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `==` operator does not work as you expect on `NaN`, instead use `Double.IsNaN(x)`.

Comment: It "works" - it just doesn't return `true` for two `NaN`s.

Comment: It is, in fact, a specific characteristic of `NaN` that a `NaN` value is not equal to itself.  There is also more than one valid representation of `NaN`.