# Double.TryParse - not working properly

Tags: vb.net

i was suprised when value "NaN" comming into check of below code was recognized as correct value for double parse :O and went into if and nto else... Do you know why is that and how to secure my code better to avoid such situation. Value should go to if only if number can be converted to double.

```
 If Double.TryParse(array(3), doubleitem) Then

                array(3) = doubleitem
            Else
                array(3) = Nothing
            End If
```

[image]

Comment: when array(3) value was "NaN" it went to the line: array(3) = doubleitem

Comment: i have to for specific reasons only one i cant figure out that Double.Try parse recognize some strings as cooreect values for Parse. How to avoid such situation? I thought Double.TryParse will be enough but seems not.

Comment: not it receivs true in my case. Array is string type

Comment: Try && doubleitem <> Double.NaN ?

Comment: I see, it returns true if i use `InvariantCulture`: `Double.TryParse("NaN",NumberStyles.None,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, doubleitem)`. In my culture(de-de) ` `doubleitem.ToString` returns `"n. def."`.

Comment: see main post for picture, why it happens? :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a misbehavior of `Double.TryParse`, but a Misunderstanding on your side.
The `Double` structure actually contains a constant called [`NaN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that represents a value that is not a number. 
So when you do a `Double.TryParse` on the string `"NaN"`, your result is `Double.NaN` which is a valid value for double.

Change your condition to this

```
If Double.TryParse(array(3), doubleitem) andalso not Double.IsNaN(doubleitem) Then
     array(3) = doubleitem
Else
     array(3) = Nothing
End If
```

and everything should work.

Comment: is there any other situation which could be added to avoid similar situation or its enough?

Comment: @StackUser: using the correct datatype in the first place. Why have you strings like `NaN` in an array that stores numbers?

Comment: I don't think so, I've tried by using a simple [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bh81Zx) to test for other Double constants but they didn't seem to be passing the Double.TryParse.

Answer (score 3):

You can try-parse it using `InvariantCulture`(since other languages use different names for `NaN`) and then check explicitly if it's `<>` [`Double.NaN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
If Double.TryParse(array(3), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, doubleitem) _
    AndAlso Not double.IsNaN(doubleitem) Then
    ' ... '
Else
    ' ... '
End If
```

You have to use [`Double.IsNan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264491.aspx) to check if a number is a double, [you cannot compare it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145443/why-is-double-nan-not-equal-to-itself).

Comment: Actually, you can't use `<> Double.NaN`, since it will always return true.

Comment: this version not working, but thanks for support Tim

Comment: I noticed it myself, use `double.IsNaN(doubleitem)`

Comment: ok now which version is "better",within your Tim you also added CultureInfo.

Comment: If you are working in a multilingual environment, then go for the `TryParse` overload that uses the `CultureInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Three correct solutions are:

```
Console.WriteLine( 0/zero = Double.NaN )
Console.WriteLine( 0/zero <> Double.NaN )
Console.WriteLine( Double.IsNaN(0/zero) )
```

0/zero being your doubleitem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264491.aspx